# What is wrong with my simple query?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I'm new to Linq to Xml. I have a very simple xml file like this:

```
<Items>
    <Item>
       <Stuff>Strings</Stuff>
    </Item>
    <Item>
       <Stuff>Strings</Stuff>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

And I'm trying to query it like this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(myStream)
from node in doc.Descendants(XName.Get("Item"))
    select new { Stuff = node.Element(XName.Get("Stuff")).Value }
```

But doc.Descendents(XName.Get("Item")) returns null. Something is wrong with my understanding here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code actually works:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string xml = @"
                <Items>
                    <Item>
                        <Stuff>Strings</Stuff>
                    </Item>
                    <Item>
                        <Stuff>Strings</Stuff>
                    </Item>
                </Items>";

    using (StringReader myStream = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(myStream);

        var query = from node in doc.Descendants(XName.Get("Item"))
                    select new { Stuff = 
                        node.Element(XName.Get("Stuff")).Value };

        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Stuff: {0}", item.Stuff);
        }
    }
```

It should be noted that if the elements are not qualified with namespaces, then you don't really need XName:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string xml = @"
                <Items>
                    <Item>
                        <Stuff>Strings</Stuff>
                    </Item>
                    <Item>
                        <Stuff>Strings</Stuff>
                    </Item>
                </Items>";

    using (StringReader myStream = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(myStream);

        var query = from node in doc.Descendants("Item")
                    select new { Stuff = node.Element("Stuff").Value };

        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Stuff: {0}", item.Stuff);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right. It does work. But when I break with the debugger and start examining the object model with the command window, it does not work. I never actually tried executing it without stepping through. Do you have any insight into this?

Comment: I broke on the line containing the linq query and executed
"? doc.Descendants("Item")"
in the command window.

Comment: @BC: If you put it in the watch window, you get null?  Or it says that it throws an exception?

Comment: If I put doc.Descendants("Item") in the watch, the value before and after the query is "This expression causes side effects and will not be evaluated."

Comment: Maybe it can it only be evaluated once?

Comment: @BC: No, you should be able to evaluate it multiple times.  You need to post a complete code example, and detail where you set the break, as well as what you are trying to observe.

Comment: I can force the evaluation multiple times in the watch using the little recycle icon. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using doc.Root.Decendants("Item")

Answer (score 0):

There's an implicit conversion from System.String to XName, so the more usual form is

```
...doc.Descendants("Item")
```

and

```
...node.Element("Stuff").Value
```

Besides that, I suggest doc.Root.Descendants() as in the previous answer.  The document is still at the "top" of the hierarchy when it's loaded.  I was under the impression that Descendants() was recursive, but who knows, right?